# Can't install plugin Spring Tool Suite 4 in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

CentOS 7

Eclipse Oxygen 2

Java 8

I add the next url and want to install plugin **Spring Tool Suite  4** for Eclipse Oxygen.

Help here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4

So I input the next url:

https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.19/

But it can't install
[image]

Error:

```
Can't perform operation....
```

Comment: The Marketplace link clearly says "Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19), 2020-12 (4.18), 2020-09 (4.17)", Oxygen (4.7) is way too old.

Comment: @greg-449 I found url: https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.19/  . This work. And now I have Spring Tool Suite in Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link because it works well:

> https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.12/

**UPDATE:**

You can use the latest version of STS4 p2 repo: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Previous-Versions

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Links can become broken over time, can you add some information in case the link breaks?

Comment: @Fred you can use the latest version of STS4: https://download.springsource.com/releases/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.24/